# One author, two affiliations

Tags: author

I keep finding answers to similar questions, which do not apply to me, or do not respect the constraints I have. So I'm posting a new one. I am a single author of a paper, and I have two affiliations. I would like to obtain the following effect:

> My name^{1,2}
>
> 1. My first affiliation
> 2. My second affiliation

And here are my comments and constraints:

- I must use the `\thanks` command for at least the first affiliation, as this is imposed by the editors of the publication.
- I cannot use the package `authblk` or other packages.
- The numbers 1,2 above are for reference only. I can use any footnote marks. However,
- I intend to display a separate footnote mark for the affiliation, so breaking a line in the first footnote, and display only the number `1.` is not an option.
- I normally see this question answered with multiple authors and multiple affiliations, for which I understand there is a solution, but does not seem to apply to my case.

Comment: Which documentclass are you going to use? Best give a small, but complete (compilable) example that illustrates your basic document setup. Without it, it is difficult to give a reliable answer.

Comment: One possible approach (and rather a cop-out) is to enter them together, separated by a semicolon,  If the usual footnote presentation is used for `\thanks`, you could also try putting them onto separate lines by entering them as `affiliation 1.\endgraf affiliation 2.`

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know what will work without knowing your documentclass.  Does this work for you?

```
Chris Q. Doe\thanks{My first institution}\supit{b} 

\supit{b}My second institution
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use two `\thanks` commands? You could use `\,` to separate the footnote marks or even do something like `$^{,}$` to get your superscript comma.

Comment: Good idea, but how these will be presented depends unambiguously on what document class is being used.  For example, AMS article document classes put `\thanks`es on the first page, and affiliations on the last page.

Comment: (Good to see you, Barbara)

The handling of authors and affiliations is a bit of a mess in LaTeX in general. Unfortunately, the default classes set up a situation which doesn't translate well to many journals' formats so the correct input ends up not being document class–agnostic.